# mounting volume protected against user access

Tags: linux, security, permissions, mount

I need to mount a directory in a way that prevents user accessing it. However I need to have access to all attributes (including permission) from root. Is following method safe or is there a way around it:

```
mkdir /mnt/protect
chmod 700 /mnt/protect
mkdir /mnt/protect/some_dir
mount /dev/sdXn /mnt/protect/some_dir
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is should be secure, since any non-root user will not be able to read or enter any directory under `/mnt/protect` - that is *unless* you make something stupid like create a hard link to some file under `/mnt/protect/` in a place that is accessible to others.

*[Edit]:*
As Maciej has pointed out, it is actually (almost always?) forbidden to create cross-device hardlinks. What you could (but, of course **should never**) do is create a bind mount to some place under the "protected" filesystem. That would constitute a security breach.

Comment: Note: it is possible to use chmod 700 on the root of the mounted filesystem **after** it has been mounted. This way you don't have to remember that you want it protected.

Comment: @Stéph I confess that, at first, I didn't get what you mean. But now I see that you propose a different approach to the whole problem - yours works per-filesystem (regardless of the mountpoint) and Maciej's is per-mountpoint (regardless of mounted filesystems).

Comment: Last time I've check it wasn't possible to do hard links to directories or cross-filesystems (of course that are the features of specific filesystems ;) ).

Comment: To directories, you can't make a hardlink (that is why I wrote *create a hard link to some file*. But for cross-filesystem links - good point, Macieju :)